# REST Works on some computers

Tags: rest, maven, jakarta-ee, glassfish

This is really confusing, i have a rest service that works on some computers but refuses to work on others, no idea why.

The project is using Maven, EJB and glassfish

This is the rest service:

```
@Path("/")
public class ArticleService {

@EJB
private LocalArticle articleEJB;

@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
@Path("article/{articleId}")
public Article getArticleXML(@PathParam("articleId") int id) {  
    return articleEJB.getArticleById(id);
}

@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("article/{articleId}")
public Article getArticleJSON(@PathParam("articleId") int id) {
    return articleEJB.getArticleById(id);
}
}
```

The return value is a object, and if i instead return article.getName i get a 200 response, however if i try to return the entire object i get 500

Here is a rest management class(I'm not sure what this does, I followed an example from a book):

```
@ApplicationPath("rest")
public class ArticleMgmtRESTApplication extends ResourceConfig {

    public ArticleMgmtRESTApplication () {
        packages("se.alager.rest.ws.services");
    }
}
}
```

Here is the Article in question:

```
@Entity
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name="Article.findAll", query="SELECT a FROM Article a"),
    @NamedQuery(name="Article.findById", query="SELECT a FROM Article a  WHERE a.id = :id")
})
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Article implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name="id_article")
    @XmlAttribute
    private int id;
    private int amount;
    private String description;
    private String name;
}
```

This exact code works flawlessly for mt friend, but I can't seem to get it to work, any ideas as to why?

Here is the Glassfish log for the error (ther was some 500 more lines of log, I hope this is relevant, I have no idea what I'm doing here)

```
[2016-10-20T16:31:44.140+0200] [glassfish 4.1]
[INFO] [] [org.jboss.weld.Bootstrap]
[tid: _ThreadID=142 _ThreadName=admin-listener(7)] [timeMillis: 1476973904140] 
[levelValue: 800] [[
WELD-000119: Not generating any bean definitions from 
org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.inject.ParamConverters$CharacterProvider
because of underlying class loading error: Type [unknown] not found. 
If this is unexpected, enable DEBUG logging to see the full error.]]

[2016-10-20T16:31:45.000+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] 
[org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.init.JerseyServletContainerInitializer] 
[tid: _ThreadID=142 _ThreadName=admin-listener(7)] [timeMillis: 1476973905000] 
[levelValue: 800] [[
Registering the Jersey servlet application, named 
se.alager.rest.ws.ManagementRESTApplication, 
at the servlet mapping /rest/*, with the Application class of the same name.]]
```

Comment: A "500" error is a server exception. It will have been logged. Post the relevant piece of the log file to get more help.